# How to Solve Uploading to SQLite is Very Slow when Database Larger

Tags: php, database, sqlite, pdo

My PHP script was generating database to SQLite file (db/source) which place in different folder of admin path (admin/import.php).

It working with PDO_Connect, PDO_FetchOne, PDO_FetchRow, PDO_FetchAll, and etc.

I notice when I upload first CSV file that contains 2,500 rows. It working fine and very fast to uploading just 4-5 seconds.

But after that when I uploading more and more files that make a database size larger. This will increasing long time to uploading. If total data in database more than 30,000, it will using time over 180 seconds or more in uploading. That exceed max_execution_time on the Server and it not completed full uploading.

So, I need to find a solution to reduce uploading file if database size larger.

Comment: If you have to do this regularly, you should upload the file and add a job to a queue. Then you can setup a cron-job to process the queue periodically and as that is done from the command line, it will not be affected by `max_execution_time`.

Comment: My script hasn't cron-job integrated, it working with pure PHP. I'm working by iMacros in file uploading. But as I notice, it will take slow and slower when database file larger (Not related cron-job or queue process.